# blocking pop-ups resulting from selenium firefox driver

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am attempting to scrape websites using selenium-python. I am trying to use firefox driver (since PhantomJS doesn't work on me), but is there way to block the pop-ups when using the firefox driver?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

Even I turn on "disable pop ups" in FireFox manually, it's not working for all website. A work around is switch to pop up window, close it, and switch back to the original window.

Here is the code in python:

```
# Switch to new window opened
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# Close the new window
driver.close()
# Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but you can use the `dom.popup_maximum` profile preference, setting it to `0` like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("dom.popup_maximum", 0)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

url = "http://some.url.with.annoying.popups"

driver.get(url)
```

For a list of other available options, please refer to this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/697018/how-to-disable-popups-in-firefox-without-add-ons)

Answer (score 1):

Use [xvfb](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) in the framebuffer and here is a simple [usage](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/linux/system/start-and-use-xfdb-enable-x-server-on-headless-system).

It provides an X environment for selenium.